# Is this a Shonen Jump anime?

Tags: identification-request, shonen-jump

So I've had this image for a while (just been trying to find it to use in the question).

[image: Luffy, Naruto, Ichigo and Goku]

I know that all four characters are from Shonen Jump and looks (to me) like a screenshot of an actual anime, but when I try to use Google reverse image search I either get other image hosting sites tagging all the characters uploaded by various users or a [YouTube AMV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jF_pO_21VIk). (I am assuming as it is an AMV I don't have sound but the description links to a song called "Hear Me Now". Also I don't see the image in question in the video so I think it's used as a thumbnail).

So I am wondering is there a Shonen Jump anime which stars Luffy, Naruto, Ichigo and Goku?

Comment: OMG!! I would love to see what will happen if **Goku** (whose Kamehameha can _sometimes_ destroy planets) goes to the _Soul Society_ and fights **Ichigo** (whose _saigo-no-getsuga-tensho_ cannot destroy planets) and so **Naruto** steps in, uses _Oodama Rasen Shuriken_ on Goku and almost kills him when **Luffy** steps between Goku and the oodama rasen shuriken and makes it bounce of his bouncy body. What a day would it be!! Best day of my life....

Comment: You may be interested in [_J-Stars Victory VS_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-Stars_Victory_VS) and other crossover video games of _Shounen Jump_ series (_Famicom Jump: Hero Retsuden, Famicom Jump II: Saikyou no Shichinin, Cult Jump, Battle Stadium D.O.N, Jump Super Stars_, and _Jump Ultimate Stars_) which feature official crossover art.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second page of a reverse image search leads me to [this Deviant Art page](http://ladygt.deviantart.com/art/Making-of-a-crossover-fanart-207124921), where it's made clear that this is fan art. (A lot of fan edits can look reasonably professional. For example, I know of someone on YouTube who includes a lot of scenes in her AMVs which she creates with Photoshop or the such. As an example, [this *Fullmetal Alchemist* AMV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhV5spHUbT0) features a number of with Hawkeye and Mustang that are non-canon, and which the creator states as such [on her Tumblr blog](http://climbingonroofs.tumblr.com/tagged/fma%3Ab+scenes+were+mainstream+so+I+made+my+own).)

However, since it's still interesting to look at whether or not a cross-over exists, I'll take a look at that as well. It doesn't look like there's an anime starring all four, at least in that a search for any cross-over spin-offs doesn't generate anything "official". As I don't follow any of these series, this may have been insufficient.

For what it's worth, I searched for `one piece spin-off dragon ball z naruto bleach`. However, `one piece spin-off dragon ball z` did generate [this one-chapter collaboration](http://toriko.wikia.com/wiki/Toriko_Collaboration_Specials/Toriko_x_One_Piece_x_DBZ) involving both series and *Toriko*, so it can't be that my search terms are completely off. Replacing `spin-off` with `collaboration` still yields no useful, official results. Moreover, when I put the names of the series in quotation marks, all I ended up with on the first couple pages were either references to the Toriko collaboration or people comparing all four series.

Comment: there's also a shokugeki no souma [omake](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WJf4p.jpg) that features jump heroines: One Piece‘s Nami, Nisekoi‘s Chitoge, Gintama‘s Kagura, World Trigger‘s Chika Amatori, Haikyû‘s Kiyoko Shimizu and Assassination Classroom‘s Irina Jelavić aka Ms. Vitch.

Comment: Ahhh, i didn't go onto page 2 of the google results so i probably missed that Deviant Art Page

Comment: There is 1 crossover between One Piece and DBZ, but that is together with Toriko, also there is a crossover manga of One Piece and DBZ but i don't know the name sadly